# bash script: capturing tcp traffic on a remote server sometimes works, sometimes fails. No errors

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, busybox, tcpdump

**Background**

I am running BusyBox in the remote server.

I have a bash script that does two things:
1.  via ssh, starts a sub process to monitor tcp traffic using tcpdump command. Save results to a file - either on remote machine or local machine.  Tried both.
2.  starts a second sub process to generate tcp traffic.

**Code Snippet:**

```
#html_tcpdumpfile="$(ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net \"mktemp\")"
html_tcpdumpfile=$(mktemp)

test_steps=(
    #"{ ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net \"timeout -t 20 tcpdump -nvi eth0 port 5060 > "$html_tcpdumpfile" \" ; }" 
    "{ ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net \"timeout -t 20 tcpdump -i eth0 port 5060 \"> $html_tcpdumpfile; }"   
    "{ ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net \"timeout -t 15 cat /tmp/htmlemail.txt | /etc/postfix/process_email.py \"; }"
 )
pids=()
for index in ${!test_steps[@]}; do       
      (echo "${test_steps[$index]}" | bash) &
      pids[${index}]=$!
      echo "$pids[${index}] is the pid"
done

#shouldn't really need this because of the timers but... just in case...
for pid in ${pids[*]}; 
do   
  wait $pid; 
done;
# ============ ANALYZE TEST RESULTS
echo "========== html_tcpdumpfile CONTENTS ============="
cat $html_tcpdumpfile
echo "========== html_tcpdumpfile CONTENTS ============="
```

**Problem**

Sometimes, the tcpdump command doesn't capture anything, and at other times it does. There are no error messages when it fails to capture.

**What I've tried So far**

1. As you can see, I've tried to change the location of the dump file between the remote machine and the local one.  That doesn't seem to make a difference.
2. I've proven that TCP traffic is ALWAYS generated... each time I run the script because I have another ssh session open and i can see the traffic being generated.  It's just that my script intermittently fails to capture it.
3. I've tried to increase the timeout value on the tcp session to something huge to make sure I give it enough time.  But I don't think that's the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I tried to introduce a sleep in between launching each subprocess:

```
pids=()
for index in ${!test_steps[@]}; do       
      (echo "${test_steps[$index]}" | bash) &
      sleep 5
      pids[${index}]=$!
      echo "$pids[${index}] is the pid"
done
```

But that doesn't make a difference either.

**EDIT 2**

I changed the tcpdump command to look like this:

```
test_steps=(     
    "{ ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net \"timeout -t 30 tcpdump -nlc 100 -i eth0 port 5060 \"> $rtf_tcpdumpfile; }" 
    "{ ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net \"timeout -t 20 tail -f /var/log/messages \" > $syslog; }"    
    "{ ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net \"timeout -t 15 cat /tmp/htmlemail.txt | /etc/postfix/process_email.py \"; }"
 )
```

The tcpdump still fails to capture intermittently, but ... what's interesting is that the syslog is always successfully captured.  (the python script actually writes to the syslog when it's invoked and so I can see /prove that the script is working)

Comment: No space in `remotemachine.mydomain.net\"timeout` where I'd expect there should be one (between `net` and `\"`).

Comment: @Kusalananda hi that was just a typo while I created the post. The script doesn't have that issue.  Otherwise, I would get a syntax error.  I have updated my post to fix the typo!  Thanks!

Comment: Try giving tcpdump the `-l` (lowercase ell) option, to make it line buffered. Otherwise you'll only get output every 4KB or so.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Good idea, I often forget that.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I just tried that but it's still failing.  :(  But thanks for that suggestion.  I'm keeping that option in just to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you are dealing with an appliance/iOT with a limited space, I would deal with the output in the calling side, i.e. using the > after the `ssh` commands as in

```
ssh "command" > output.txt
```

As for `tcpdump` I would not kill it as a policy all the time, risking losing buffers. You might have not output maybe because of that.

I would place a limit on packets captured. I would also try not to solve DNS. As in, for capturing 100 packets:

```
tcpdump -nc 100 -i eth0 port 5600
```

When you are storing  the capture file on the local system, you should only run `cat` locally and not remotely and locally.

Likewise, when you are running both `tcpdump` and `cat` remotely, you are launching both at the same time, and both the remote and local `cat` won't have nothing to show.

Following the suggestion of @MarkPlotnick, I also added `-l`to `tcpdump` to make it line buffered. That may obviate the need for the `-c` option. I would use both.

So I would change that script for:

```
#!/bin/bash
html_tcpdumpfile=$(mktemp)

ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net "timeout -t 20 tcpdump -nlc 100 -i eth0  port 5060 " > $html_tcpdumpfile

cat $html_tcpdumpfile

rm $html_tcpdumpfile
```

Or we might not even need to create explicitly a temporary file:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net "timeout -t 20 tcpdump -nlc 100 -i eth0  port 5060 " \
| less
```

Lastly, I would advise deleting all the temp files created, specially on the remote side.

PS: the OP mentioned in comments the remote system is BusyBox and as such the `timeout` options are different than in the `coretutils` package. I also edit the question for it to mention BusyBox.

Comment: Hi there.  So unfortunately, your suggestion to add "-nlc 100" doesn't improve the situation.  I am saving the dump file locally and cat'ing the local file- only tried remote in case it made a difference but it didn't.  Also I am cleaning up after myself.  Thanks for the reminders though.  Regarding DNS - sorry, that one has to stay.

Comment: `ssh remotemachine.mydomain.net "timeout -t 20 tcpdump -lc 100 -i eth0  port 5060 " | less`  does it work?

Comment: I didn't tack on " | less" because I don't want to change more code than necessary right now... but i did change the tcpdump to REMOVE the "n" and just have "tcpdump -lc 100 -i eth0 port 5060" but that doesn't work

Comment: Did you see my EDIT 2?  Specifically, wondering if you noticed my findings with syslog?  Just wondering if this proves that the issue is with tcpdump command instead of some logic issue in the script per se.

Comment: comment the "&" and comment/delete the waitpid cycle, at the end of the day is mostly what my answer is about.